# convert string to datetimestamp like '01/21/2021 11:49:46 AM' in Bigquery

Tags: datetime, google-bigquery

In Bigquery how to convert string '01/28/2021 11:49:46 AM' to datetimestamp(please suggest if this is not the correct data type) in Bigquery.

I want to convert from string because I need to sort the data based on the datetime values in that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [parse_timestamp](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#parse_timestamp):

```
select parse_timestamp('%m/%d/%Y %r', '01/28/2021 11:49:46 AM')
```